# Maltego stuck in Loading Modules

Tags: process, kali-linux, vmware

I'm using Kali Linux 2016 on Vmware 12 player.

I'm trying to run maltego(first time) and it's stuck on loading modules.

[image: Maltego stuck on this window:]

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Below link fixes your issue.

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

http://csabak.blogspot.in/2016/02/cannot-start-maltigo-on-kali-linux-20.html